# Should a re-serve be called if Referee and Line Judge disagree?

Tags: officiating, volleyball, serve

It was the last game of a volleyball tournament when a serve hit the baseline of the opponent's court - as to me it seemed. From the referee's perch, she instantly called it out. But then the line judge shook his head, and called it in. A small argument broke out and a re-serve was called.

What should have actually happened in this situation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All calls in volleyball eventually come from the head referee. However, he or she can ask their assistants for assistance if they didn't have a good view of the play. If the referee cannot make a decision based on their own view and those of the assistants, calling a replay is perfectly fine.

It's similar to basketball. When the officials cannot decide the correct outcome of a play, they sometimes call a "jump ball" to determine the outcome.